# Set Windows Network Profile to Public using C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to programatically set the Windows OS Network Profile for the Ethernet Adapter to "Public"

In PowerShell, I can use this:

`Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 3" -NetworkCategory Public`

I'm new to C# and looking for a way, in my app, to set the Network Profile for the Ethernet Adapter to "Public". To clarify, this is the Ethernet Adapter in the Windows 10 OS that needs to be set to "Public"

Here is the code I have now, but this does not set the Network Profile

```
public async Task<bool> HasInternet()
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
    var _Profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    if (_Profile == null)
        return false;
    var net = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    return _Profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel().Equals(net);
}
```

Will something like this work? (Code I found on SO)

```
get { return (Profile & NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC) != 0; }
set
{
    // Check if value isn't changing
    if (value == IsPublicProfile) return;

    if (value)
        Profile |= NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
    else
        Profile &= ~NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
}
```

Comment: "Will something like this work?" Have you tried it? What happens when you try?

Comment: I'm not sure how I could test it out - guess that's part of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell cmdlets can be called directly from C#. You could use System.Management.Automation to create a Powershell pipeline and then run your cmdlet as outlined [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-6)

For your requirements, you could do this

```
PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Set-NetConnectionProfile")
               .AddParameter("InterfaceAlias", "Ethernet 3")
               .AddParameter("NetworkCategory", "Public")
               .Invoke();
```

Invoke() should return the type PSObject from which you can parse properties for further use.

You will need to ensure you have the System.Automation.Management assembly referenced which is outlined at the [beginning of this blog post from Microsoft.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

Comment: This would work, and is really helpful, but I'm looking for a way to do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Code changing the network category must be run with Admin rights.
Otherwise a Win32Exception returning E_ACCESS_DENIED might be thrown when setting the category.

If you have the InterfaceIndex, convert it to the InterfaceLuid and then to the InterfaceGuid:

```
[DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private extern static int ConvertInterfaceIndexToLuid(uint interfaceIndex, ref ulong InterfaceLuid);

[DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private extern static int ConvertInterfaceLuidToGuid(ref ulong InterfaceLuid, ref Guid InterfaceGuid);

private static int ConvertInterfaceIndexToGuid(uint interfaceIndex, out Guid interfaceGuid)
{
    ulong interfaceLuid = 0;
    interfaceGuid = new Guid();
    int errorCode = ConvertInterfaceIndexToLuid(interfaceIndex, ref interfaceLuid);
    if (errorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        errorCode = ConvertInterfaceLuidToGuid(ref interfaceLuid, ref interfaceGuid);
    }

    return errorCode;
}
```

If you have the InterfaceGuid, use the WindowsApiCodePack (can be the very first version from some 15 years ago) to iterate through the networks (using the INetworkListManager wrapper), find the adapter in that list and set the category for the network:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Net;

private static bool SetNetworkCategory(Guid interfaceGuid)
{
    NetworkCollection networks = NetworkListManager.GetNetworks(NetworkConnectivityLevels.Connected);

    foreach (Network network in networks)
    {
        foreach (NetworkConnection connection in network.Connections)
        {
            if (interfaceGuid.Equals(connection.AdapterId))
            {
                network.Category = NetworkCategory.Public;

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```