# C# - Change network profile to public or private

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, networking

I want to change the network profile to private, [this to be specific.](https://s14635.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/windows10_changelocation_public.jpg)

I have already tried PowerShell commands in my project as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058838/set-windows-network-profile-to-public-using-c-sharp)

```
PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Set-NetConnectionProfile")
           .AddParameter("InterfaceAlias", "Ethernet")
           .AddParameter("NetworkCategory", "Private")
           .Invoke();
```

I have tried another approach like this

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript("Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -NetworkCategory Public");       
            ps.Invoke();
```

But it ends up in error **Provider Load Failure** with elevated access too. I have tried it on 2 PCs.
If I write the command `Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -NetworkCategory Private` in PowerShell directly it works like a charm.

So... I'm stuck

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It does not have to be a PowerShell script.

Thanks.

Comment: is your app running as administrator?

Comment: yes, its there (with elevated access)